# How do I get a fixed positioned footer, fixed width right column, left column for the rest using CSS lay-out?

Tags: html, css, layout

My problem seems very basic but I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to create a lay-out with no header, a footer always at the bottom and two columns. The right column has a fixed width (770px) and the left column should use the rest of the space. In the left column OpenLayers will be used which will fetch Google Maps images to fill the space.

The page needs to be visible on smaller screens as well and should work in FF, Chrome and IE7+.
I'm starting with a wrapper that has a min-width of 1200px. This is for the smaller screens. Scrollbars will appear then.
Next I've created 3 divs inside the wrapper: leftframe, rightframe, bottomframe.
The bottomframe used this CSS:

```
bottom: 0; 
height: auto; 
left: 0; 
overflow: hidden; 
position: fixed; 
right: 0; 
top: auto; 
width: auto; 
min-width: 700px; 
z-index: 5000;
```

This works good. The footer is always nicely at the bottom.

Now the problem comes. When I resize my viewport or show the page on a small screen the leftframe must resize to fill the remaining space. I've tried a lot: floats, positions.
What seems to be working is to absolute position the right frame and give the left frame a margin-right the same as the width of the right frame (770px):

```
#leftframe { 
  width:auto; 
  height: 100%; 
  margin-right: 770px;
}
#rightframe {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 770px;
}
```

This seems to work as well. At least for the width.

The right frame is dynamically filled with data I get using AJAX. In some occasions the returned data is larger than the min-height I've given to the wrapper. This is fine for the right frame, its height is adjusted but the height of the wrapper isn't and thus the height of the left frame isn't adjusted as well. This result in a right frame that is higher than my left frame and a blank space is between my left frame and footer.

How to solve this? Preferable without using jQuery or similar but with CSS only.

[Edit]
Using the example provided by Zuul I've created these few lines of jQuery and it seems to work now.
These lines are called when I'm finished processing the AJAX data.

```
var currentHeightRight = parseInt($("#rightframe").css("height").replace("px", ""), 10);
var currentHeightWrapper = parseInt($("#wrap").css("height").replace("px", ""), 10);
if (currentHeightRight > currentHeightWrapper)
{ 
  $("#wrap").css("height", currentHeightRight);
  $("#map").css("height", currentHeightRight);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, I've made a Fiddle to show a way to deal with your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/TdTCU/

Additionally, there's a button there, to simulate the global resize :)

**Notes:**

The better solution for this kind of problems is the absolute position of elements inside a wrapper. Basically setting up a structure for all rest.

Comment: Thanks @zuul your example seems nice. But I don't understand how it works when resizing the viewport. I tried resizing the fiddle output pane, but that didn't made the left column wider or smaller.

Comment: Press the button, the button simulates the resize... basically, the structure grows and shrinks dynamically using as a reference point the size of the wrapper! If your wrapper gets a width in percentage, it will grown and shrink accordingly with the view-port size! (for this test, I've used a fixed width to allow you to understand whats going on)

Comment: I've updated my question with a solution based on your example.

Comment: @Paul Meems, please see the css used on the Fiddle example, there you will find that elements (left and right) are forced to be all the way to the bottom, thus being always with the same height! There's no need for Javascript on this!